# How I prevent to get latest or check-in a specific file automatically in Team Foundation Server?

Tags: c#, wcf, tfs

I work on a team that works on a project. I change my project web config file to set a specific connection string but when I check-in or get latest version of project it changes to others connection strings. I have same problem in WCF Service references. appconfig and xsd files of service references always corrupted when I check-in or get latest version of program from tfs and I have to delete service references and add it again! How can I get rid of this?

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue on our project (with connection strings), and found a good solution: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494(v=vs.110).aspx

By adding a connections.config file for each developer with his own connection string, we just needed to say that this file must not be a part of Source Control. Then in the web.config connectionString section, you just refer to the connections.config file.

Just be aware that you need to either transform your web.config or add the connections.config when publishing the site.

I know you can do the same about the appSettings section in the web.config.

How you do it with WCF, I don't know - but it sounds strange to me that your are not using the same WCF refence.

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions.

1. The team uses the same configuration (e.g. everyone uses localhost references)
2. You separate user from application settings (do not apply to all kind of settings nor projects)
3. Use transforms and solution configuration to map have per-environment setting
4. Use `configSource` to move config section in separate files that are not under version control

I do not think there is a perfect solution, but maybe you apply a mix of these. I strongly suggest to apply them in the stated order.